# Excel VBA add value in specific cells

Tags: excel, vba, loops

Got help from you guys to create a code to copy some value from one workbook to another. I have one more question though.
I would like to write som static information in a cell in column J on the same row as the other copied information.
How do I add that to the loop?

I´ve tried:

```
wsDest.Cells(DestRow, "J").Value = "HVD"
```

But it only adds the value in the first row not the rest. No errors but it seems as it doesn't loop as the other code inside the **For Each**.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CopyCells()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet 'define source sheet
    Set wsSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Blad1")

    Dim wbDest As Workbook 'define destination workbook
    Set wbDest = Workbooks.Open("C:\Temp\Ändringar bef objekt.xlsx")

    Dim wsDest As Worksheet 'define destination sheet
    Set wsDest = wbDest.Worksheets("Ändringsdata")

    Dim DestRow As Long
    DestRow = 2 'start in row 2 in destination sheet

    wsSrc.Parent.Activate: wsSrc.Activate

    Dim Rng As Range
    For Each Rng In Selection.Areas
        Rng.Resize(, 1).Copy Destination:=wsDest.Cells(DestRow, "A") 'copy A to A
        Rng.Resize(, 1).Offset(, 5).Copy Destination:=wsDest.Cells(DestRow, "D") 'copy F to D
        **wsDest.Cells(DestRow, "J").Value = "HVD" 'write HVD in column J same row**
        DestRow = DestRow + Rng.Rows.Count 'move DestRow to next free row
    Next Rng
End Sub
```

Comment: Does anyone have any sugestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstand how your `For Each` works. It doesn't loop through every row or every cell. It loops through `Areas`, which is a collection of `Range`s. Usually there's only one `Range` in this collection, but if you select cells with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> then you have more elements in `Areas`.

So, your code takes one such "Area" and copy it's first column to column A, then it's 5th column to column D and enters "HVD" into a single cell (`Cells(DestRow, "J")`). If you want to enter this value in every row you must resize this cell. And to do this you can use this:

```
wsDest.Cells(DestRow, "J").Resize(Rng.Rows.Count).Value = "HVD"
```

Also, remember that you can debug your code by putting cursor inside your macro code and pressing F8. This will run your code line by line and all changes will be immediately seen in the worksheet.

Comment: Perfect thanks for the explanation and for your help!